# Rebuild all indexes in a Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a very large SQL Server 2008 R2 database (1.5TB) and will be copying some data from column to column within the same table. I've been told that the schema has a large number of indexes and was wondering if there is a default query or script that will rebuild all the indexes. Have also been advised to update the statistics at the same time?

Each of the 30 tables has one clustered index and 13x non-clustered indexes

Thanks.

Comment: Best to use Ola Hallengren's scripts, not roll your own solution: https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html

Answer (score 153):

Try the following script:

```
Exec sp_msforeachtable 'SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON; ALTER INDEX ALL ON ? REBUILD'
GO
```

**Also**

I prefer(After a long search) to use the following script, it contains **`@fillfactor`** determines how much percentage of the space on each leaf-level page is filled with data.

```
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @fillfactor INT
SET @fillfactor = 80 
DECLARE TableCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME([object_id]))+'.' + QUOTENAME(name) AS TableName
FROM sys.tables
OPEN TableCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @TableName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
SET @sql = 'ALTER INDEX ALL ON ' + @TableName + ' REBUILD WITH (FILLFACTOR = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(3),@fillfactor) + ')'
EXEC (@sql)
FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @TableName
END
CLOSE TableCursor
DEALLOCATE TableCursor
GO
```

for more info, check the following link:

https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/01/30/sql-server-2008-2005-rebuild-every-index-of-all-tables-of-database-rebuild-index-with-fillfactor/

and if you want to Check Index Fragmentation on Indexes in a Database, try the following script:

```
SELECT dbschemas.[name] as 'Schema',
dbtables.[name] as 'Table',
dbindexes.[name] as 'Index',
indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent,
indexstats.page_count
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) AS indexstats
INNER JOIN sys.tables dbtables on dbtables.[object_id] = indexstats.[object_id]
INNER JOIN sys.schemas dbschemas on dbtables.[schema_id] = dbschemas.[schema_id]
INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS dbindexes ON dbindexes.[object_id] = indexstats.[object_id]
AND indexstats.index_id = dbindexes.index_id
WHERE indexstats.database_id = DB_ID() AND dbtables.[name] like '%%'
ORDER BY indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent desc
```

For more information, Check the following link:

http://www.schneider-electric.com/en/faqs/FA234246/

Comment: I'd just add that adding the line `PRINT @sql` after the `SET @sql = ...` line is helpful to give the user some indication of what indexes it is rebuilding and how far it has progressed.

Answer (score 16):

Here's another script to add to the list. The key difference with the other ones is that this applies general recommended threshold of rebuild if over 30% fragmentation and reorganize of over 5%. If nothing is over either, nothing happens. This allow you run this script as often as you'd like:

```sql
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
SET ARITHABORT ON
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON

DECLARE @TableName varchar(255);
DECLARE @IndexName varchar(255);
DECLARE @Fragmentation FLOAT;
DECLARE @IndexScript varchar(255);
DECLARE @Schema varchar(255);

SELECT 
    dbtables.[name], 
    dbindexes.[name],
    indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent,
    indexstats.page_count [pages]
FROM 
    sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) AS indexstats
    INNER JOIN sys.tables dbtables 
        on dbtables.[object_id] = indexstats.[object_id]
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas dbschemas 
        on dbtables.[schema_id] = dbschemas.[schema_id]
    INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS dbindexes 
        ON dbindexes.[object_id] = indexstats.[object_id]
        AND indexstats.index_id = dbindexes.index_id
WHERE 
    indexstats.database_id = DB_ID()
    AND indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent >= 5.0
    AND indexstats.page_count > 10
ORDER BY 
    indexstats.page_count ASC,
    indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent ASC

DECLARE TableCursor CURSOR FOR  
    SELECT 
        dbtables.[name], 
        dbindexes.[name],
        indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent,
        dbschemas.[name]
    FROM 
        sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) AS indexstats
        INNER JOIN sys.tables dbtables 
            on dbtables.[object_id] = indexstats.[object_id]
        INNER JOIN sys.schemas dbschemas 
            on dbtables.[schema_id] = dbschemas.[schema_id]
        INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS dbindexes 
            ON dbindexes.[object_id] = indexstats.[object_id]
            AND indexstats.index_id = dbindexes.index_id
    WHERE 
        indexstats.database_id = DB_ID()
        AND indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent >= 5.0
        AND indexstats.page_count > 10
    ORDER BY 
        indexstats.page_count ASC,
        indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent ASC;

OPEN TableCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO
    @TableName,
    @IndexName,
    @Fragmentation,
    @Schema
 
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
 
BEGIN 
    IF (@Fragmentation >= 30.0)
        SET @IndexScript = 'ALTER INDEX [' + @IndexName + '] ON ' + @Schema + '.' + @TableName + ' REBUILD';
    ELSE IF (@Fragmentation >= 5.0)
        SET @IndexScript = 'ALTER INDEX [' + @IndexName + '] ON ' + @Schema + '.' + @TableName + ' REORGANIZE';
    ELSE
        SET @IndexScript = NULL;

    IF (@IndexScript IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        --SELECT @IndexScript
        RAISERROR (@IndexScript, 10, 0) WITH NOWAIT
        WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';
        EXEC(@IndexScript); 
    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO
        @TableName,
        @IndexName,
        @Fragmentation,
        @Schema;
 
END 
 
CLOSE TableCursor;
 
DEALLOCATE TableCursor;
```

I've been using this for a couple years. The script will output a table as well as messages, which means if you're feeling like it's taking too long you can see what it's doing in semi-realtime, (if you run it in SQL Management Studio).

Comment: Nice. The only fix here is to quote names as it fails if index names contain dashes.

```
QUOTENAME(@IndexName) + ' ON ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName)
```

Answer (score 6):

Replace the "YOUR DATABASE NAME" in the query below.

```
    DECLARE @Database NVARCHAR(255)   
    DECLARE @Table NVARCHAR(255)  
    DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(1000)  

    DECLARE DatabaseCursor CURSOR READ_ONLY FOR  
    SELECT name FROM master.sys.databases   
    WHERE name IN ('YOUR DATABASE NAME')  -- databases
    AND state = 0 -- database is online
    AND is_in_standby = 0 -- database is not read only for log shipping
    ORDER BY 1  

    OPEN DatabaseCursor  

    FETCH NEXT FROM DatabaseCursor INTO @Database  
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
    BEGIN  

       SET @cmd = 'DECLARE TableCursor CURSOR READ_ONLY FOR SELECT ''['' + table_catalog + ''].['' + table_schema + ''].['' +  
       table_name + '']'' as tableName FROM [' + @Database + '].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_type = ''BASE TABLE'''   

       -- create table cursor  
       EXEC (@cmd)  
       OPEN TableCursor   

       FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @Table   
       WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
       BEGIN
          BEGIN TRY   
             SET @cmd = 'ALTER INDEX ALL ON ' + @Table + ' REBUILD' 
             PRINT @cmd -- uncomment if you want to see commands
             EXEC (@cmd) 
          END TRY
          BEGIN CATCH
             PRINT '---'
             PRINT @cmd
             PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE() 
             PRINT '---'
          END CATCH

          FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @Table   
       END   

       CLOSE TableCursor   
       DEALLOCATE TableCursor  

       FETCH NEXT FROM DatabaseCursor INTO @Database  
    END  
    CLOSE DatabaseCursor   
    DEALLOCATE DatabaseCursor
```

Answer (score 2):

Also a good script, although my laptop ran out of memory, but this was on a very large table

https://basitaalishan.com/2014/02/23/rebuild-all-indexes-on-all-tables-in-the-sql-server-database/

```
USE [<mydatabasename>]
Go

--/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
--Arguments             Data Type               Description
--------------          ------------            ------------
--@FillFactor           [int]                   Specifies a percentage that indicates how full the Database Engine should make the leaf level
--                                              of each index page during index creation or alteration. The valid inputs for this parameter
--                                              must be an integer value from 1 to 100 The default is 0.
--                                              For more information, see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177459.aspx.

--@PadIndex             [varchar](3)            Specifies index padding. The PAD_INDEX option is useful only when FILLFACTOR is specified,
--                                              because PAD_INDEX uses the percentage specified by FILLFACTOR. If the percentage specified
--                                              for FILLFACTOR is not large enough to allow for one row, the Database Engine internally
--                                              overrides the percentage to allow for the minimum. The number of rows on an intermediate
--                                              index page is never less than two, regardless of how low the value of fillfactor. The valid
--                                              inputs for this parameter are ON or OFF. The default is OFF.
--                                              For more information, see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx.

--@SortInTempDB         [varchar](3)            Specifies whether to store temporary sort results in tempdb. The valid inputs for this
--                                              parameter are ON or OFF. The default is OFF.
--                                              For more information, see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188281.aspx.

--@OnlineRebuild        [varchar](3)            Specifies whether underlying tables and associated indexes are available for queries and data
--                                              modification during the index operation. The valid inputs for this parameter are ON or OFF.
--                                              The default is OFF.
--                                              Note: Online index operations are only available in Enterprise edition of Microsoft
--                                                      SQL Server 2005 and above.
--                                              For more information, see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191261.aspx.

--@DataCompression      [varchar](4)            Specifies the data compression option for the specified index, partition number, or range of
--                                              partitions. The options  for this parameter are as follows:
--                                                  > NONE - Index or specified partitions are not compressed.
--                                                  > ROW  - Index or specified partitions are compressed by using row compression.
--                                                  > PAGE - Index or specified partitions are compressed by using page compression.
--                                              The default is NONE.
--                                              Note: Data compression feature is only available in Enterprise edition of Microsoft
--                                                      SQL Server 2005 and above.
--                                              For more information about compression, see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280449.aspx.

--@MaxDOP               [int]                   Overrides the max degree of parallelism configuration option for the duration of the index
--                                              operation. The valid input for this parameter can be between 0 and 64, but should not exceed
--                                              number of processors available to SQL Server.
--                                              For more information, see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189094.aspx.
--- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -*/

-- Ensure a USE <databasename> statement has been executed first.

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE  @Version                           [numeric] (18, 10)
        ,@SQLStatementID                    [int]
        ,@CurrentTSQLToExecute              [nvarchar](max)
        ,@FillFactor                        [int]        = 100 -- Change if needed
        ,@PadIndex                          [varchar](3) = N'OFF' -- Change if needed
        ,@SortInTempDB                      [varchar](3) = N'OFF' -- Change if needed
        ,@OnlineRebuild                     [varchar](3) = N'OFF' -- Change if needed
        ,@LOBCompaction                     [varchar](3) = N'ON' -- Change if needed
        ,@DataCompression                   [varchar](4) = N'NONE' -- Change if needed
        ,@MaxDOP                            [int]        = NULL -- Change if needed
        ,@IncludeDataCompressionArgument    [char](1);

IF OBJECT_ID(N'TempDb.dbo.#Work_To_Do') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Work_To_Do
CREATE TABLE #Work_To_Do
    (
      [sql_id] [int] IDENTITY(1, 1)
                     PRIMARY KEY ,
      [tsql_text] [varchar](1024) ,
      [completed] [bit]
    )

SET @Version = CAST(LEFT(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY(N'ProductVersion') AS [nvarchar](128)), CHARINDEX('.', CAST(SERVERPROPERTY(N'ProductVersion') AS [nvarchar](128))) - 1) + N'.' + REPLACE(RIGHT(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY(N'ProductVersion') AS [nvarchar](128)), LEN(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY(N'ProductVersion') AS [nvarchar](128))) - CHARINDEX('.', CAST(SERVERPROPERTY(N'ProductVersion') AS [nvarchar](128)))), N'.', N'') AS [numeric](18, 10))

IF @DataCompression IN (N'PAGE', N'ROW', N'NONE')
    AND (
        @Version >= 10.0
        AND SERVERPROPERTY(N'EngineEdition') = 3
        )
BEGIN
    SET @IncludeDataCompressionArgument = N'Y'
END

IF @IncludeDataCompressionArgument IS NULL
BEGIN
    SET @IncludeDataCompressionArgument = N'N'
END

INSERT INTO #Work_To_Do ([tsql_text], [completed])
SELECT 'ALTER INDEX [' + i.[name] + '] ON' + SPACE(1) + QUOTENAME(t2.[TABLE_CATALOG]) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t2.[TABLE_SCHEMA]) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t2.[TABLE_NAME]) + SPACE(1) + 'REBUILD WITH (' + SPACE(1) + + CASE
        WHEN @PadIndex IS NULL
            THEN 'PAD_INDEX =' + SPACE(1) + CASE i.[is_padded]
                    WHEN 1
                        THEN 'ON'
                    WHEN 0
                        THEN 'OFF'
                    END
        ELSE 'PAD_INDEX =' + SPACE(1) + @PadIndex
        END + CASE
        WHEN @FillFactor IS NULL
            THEN ', FILLFACTOR =' + SPACE(1) + CONVERT([varchar](3), REPLACE(i.[fill_factor], 0, 100))
        ELSE ', FILLFACTOR =' + SPACE(1) + CONVERT([varchar](3), @FillFactor)
        END + CASE
        WHEN @SortInTempDB IS NULL
            THEN ''
        ELSE ', SORT_IN_TEMPDB =' + SPACE(1) + @SortInTempDB
        END + CASE
        WHEN @OnlineRebuild IS NULL
            THEN ''
        ELSE ', ONLINE =' + SPACE(1) + @OnlineRebuild
        END + ', STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE =' + SPACE(1) + CASE st.[no_recompute]
        WHEN 0
            THEN 'OFF'
        WHEN 1
            THEN 'ON'
        END + ', ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS =' + SPACE(1) + CASE i.[allow_row_locks]
        WHEN 0
            THEN 'OFF'
        WHEN 1
            THEN 'ON'
        END + ', ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS =' + SPACE(1) + CASE i.[allow_page_locks]
        WHEN 0
            THEN 'OFF'
        WHEN 1
            THEN 'ON'
        END + CASE
        WHEN @IncludeDataCompressionArgument = N'Y'
            THEN CASE
                    WHEN @DataCompression IS NULL
                        THEN ''
                    ELSE ', DATA_COMPRESSION =' + SPACE(1) + @DataCompression
                    END
        ELSE ''
        END + CASE
        WHEN @MaxDop IS NULL
            THEN ''
        ELSE ', MAXDOP =' + SPACE(1) + CONVERT([varchar](2), @MaxDOP)
        END + SPACE(1) + ')'
    ,0
FROM [sys].[tables] t1
INNER JOIN [sys].[indexes] i ON t1.[object_id] = i.[object_id]
    AND i.[index_id] > 0
    AND i.[type] IN (1, 2)
INNER JOIN [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES] t2 ON t1.[name] = t2.[TABLE_NAME]
    AND t2.[TABLE_TYPE] = 'BASE TABLE'
INNER JOIN [sys].[stats] AS st WITH (NOLOCK) ON st.[object_id] = t1.[object_id]
    AND st.[name] = i.[name]

SELECT @SQLStatementID = MIN([sql_id])
FROM #Work_To_Do
WHERE [completed] = 0

WHILE @SQLStatementID IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SELECT @CurrentTSQLToExecute = [tsql_text]
    FROM #Work_To_Do
    WHERE [sql_id] = @SQLStatementID

    PRINT @CurrentTSQLToExecute

    EXEC [sys].[sp_executesql] @CurrentTSQLToExecute

    UPDATE #Work_To_Do
    SET [completed] = 1
    WHERE [sql_id] = @SQLStatementID

    SELECT @SQLStatementID = MIN([sql_id])
    FROM #Work_To_Do
    WHERE [completed] = 0
END
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @Database NVARCHAR(255)   
DECLARE @Table NVARCHAR(255)  
DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(1000)  

DECLARE DatabaseCursor CURSOR READ_ONLY FOR  
SELECT name FROM master.sys.databases   
WHERE name NOT IN ('master','msdb','tempdb','model','distribution')  -- databases to exclude
--WHERE name IN ('DB1', 'DB2') -- use this to select specific databases and comment out line above
AND state = 0 -- database is online
AND is_in_standby = 0 -- database is not read only for log shipping
ORDER BY 1  

OPEN DatabaseCursor  

FETCH NEXT FROM DatabaseCursor INTO @Database  
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  

   SET @cmd = 'DECLARE TableCursor CURSOR READ_ONLY FOR SELECT ''['' + table_catalog + ''].['' + table_schema + ''].['' +  
   table_name + '']'' as tableName FROM [' + @Database + '].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_type = ''BASE TABLE'''   

   -- create table cursor  
   EXEC (@cmd)  
   OPEN TableCursor   

   FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @Table   
   WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
   BEGIN
      BEGIN TRY   
         SET @cmd = 'ALTER INDEX ALL ON ' + @Table + ' REBUILD' 
         --PRINT @cmd -- uncomment if you want to see commands
         EXEC (@cmd) 
      END TRY
      BEGIN CATCH
         PRINT '---'
         PRINT @cmd
         PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE() 
         PRINT '---'
      END CATCH

      FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @Table   
   END   

   CLOSE TableCursor   
   DEALLOCATE TableCursor  

   FETCH NEXT FROM DatabaseCursor INTO @Database  
END  
CLOSE DatabaseCursor   
DEALLOCATE DatabaseCursor
```

Answer (score 1):

[Daniel's script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43254729/241211) appears to be a good all encompassing solution, but even he admitted that his laptop ran out of memory.  Here is an option I came up with.  I based my procedure off of [Mohammad Nizamuddin's post](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Script-for-rebuilding-all-8d079754) on TechNet.  I added an initial cursor loop that pulls all the database names into a temporary table and then uses that to pull all the base table names from each of those databases.

You can optionally pass the fill factor you would prefer and specify a target database if you do not want to re-index all databases.

---

```
--===============================================================
-- Name:  sp_RebuildAllIndexes
-- Arguments:  [Fill Factor], [Target Database name]
-- Purpose:  Loop through all the databases on a server and
--           compile a list of all the table within them.
--           This list is then used to rebuild indexes for
--           all the tables in all the database.  Optionally,
--           you may pass a specific database name if you only
--           want to reindex that target database.
--================================================================
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_RebuildAllIndexes(
    @FillFactor     INT = 90,
    @TargetDatabase NVARCHAR(100) = NULL)
AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @TablesToReIndex TABLE (
            TableName VARCHAR(200)
        );
        DECLARE @DbName VARCHAR(50);
        DECLARE @TableSelect VARCHAR(MAX);
        DECLARE @DatabasesToIndex CURSOR;

        IF ISNULL( @TargetDatabase, '' ) = ''
          SET @DatabasesToIndex = CURSOR
          FOR SELECT NAME
              FROM   master..sysdatabases
        ELSE
          SET @DatabasesToIndex = CURSOR
          FOR SELECT NAME
              FROM   master..sysdatabases
              WHERE  NAME = @TargetDatabase

        OPEN DatabasesToIndex

        FETCH NEXT FROM DatabasesToIndex INTO @DbName

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
            BEGIN
                SET @TableSelect = 'INSERT INTO @TablesToReIndex SELECT CONCAT(TABLE_CATALOG, ''.'', TABLE_SCHEMA, ''.'', TABLE_NAME) AS TableName FROM '
                                   + @DbName
                                   + '.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = ''base table''';

                EXEC sp_executesql
                    @TableSelect;

                FETCH NEXT FROM DatabasesToIndex INTO @DbName
            END

        CLOSE DatabasesToIndex

        DEALLOCATE DatabasesToIndex

        DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(255)
        DECLARE TableCursor CURSOR FOR
            SELECT TableName
            FROM   @TablesToReIndex

        OPEN TableCursor

        FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @TableName

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
            BEGIN
                DBCC DBREINDEX(@TableName, ' ', @FillFactor)

                FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @TableName
            END

        CLOSE TableCursor

        DEALLOCATE TableCursor
    END
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @String NVARCHAR(MAX);
USE Databse Name;
SELECT @String
    =
(
    SELECT 'ALTER INDEX [' + dbindexes.[name] + '] ON [' + db.name + '].[' + dbschemas.[name] + '].[' + dbtables.[name]
           + '] REBUILD PARTITION = ALL WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE);' + CHAR(10) AS [text()]
    FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) AS indexstats
        INNER JOIN sys.tables dbtables
            ON dbtables.[object_id] = indexstats.[object_id]
        INNER JOIN sys.schemas dbschemas
            ON dbtables.[schema_id] = dbschemas.[schema_id]
        INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS dbindexes
            ON dbindexes.[object_id] = indexstats.[object_id]
               AND indexstats.index_id = dbindexes.index_id
        INNER JOIN sys.databases AS db
            ON db.database_id = indexstats.database_id
    WHERE dbindexes.name IS NOT NULL
          AND indexstats.database_id = DB_ID()
          AND indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent >= 10
    ORDER BY indexstats.page_count DESC
    FOR XML PATH('')
);
EXEC (@String);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is taking @ShortFuse answer and modifying if the tables are not in the default schema:

```
use Stat

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
SET ARITHABORT ON
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON

DECLARE @TableName varchar(255);
DECLARE @IndexName varchar(255);
DECLARE @SchemaName varchar(255);
DECLARE @Fragmentation FLOAT;
DECLARE @IndexScript varchar(255);

SELECT 
    dbtables.[name], 
    dbindexes.[name],
    indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent,
    indexstats.page_count [pages]
FROM 
    sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) AS indexstats
    INNER JOIN sys.tables dbtables 
        on dbtables.[object_id] = indexstats.[object_id]
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas dbschemas 
        on dbtables.[schema_id] = dbschemas.[schema_id]
    INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS dbindexes 
        ON dbindexes.[object_id] = indexstats.[object_id]
        AND indexstats.index_id = dbindexes.index_id
WHERE 
    indexstats.database_id = DB_ID()
    AND indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent >= 5.0
    AND indexstats.page_count > 10
ORDER BY 
    indexstats.page_count ASC,
    indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent ASC

DECLARE TableCursor CURSOR FOR  
    SELECT 
        dbtables.[name], 
        dbindexes.[name],
        dbschemas.[name],
        indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent 
    FROM 
        sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) AS indexstats
        INNER JOIN sys.tables dbtables 
            on dbtables.[object_id] = indexstats.[object_id]
        INNER JOIN sys.schemas dbschemas 
            on dbtables.[schema_id] = dbschemas.[schema_id]
        INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS dbindexes 
            ON dbindexes.[object_id] = indexstats.[object_id]
            AND indexstats.index_id = dbindexes.index_id
    WHERE 
        indexstats.database_id = DB_ID()
        AND indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent >= 5.0
        AND indexstats.page_count > 10
    ORDER BY 
        dbschemas.[name],
        dbtables.[name];

OPEN TableCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO
    @TableName,
    @IndexName,
    @SchemaName,
    @Fragmentation
 
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
 
BEGIN 
    IF (@Fragmentation >= 30.0)
        SET @IndexScript = 'ALTER INDEX ' + @IndexName + ' ON ' + @SchemaName + '.' + @TableName + ' REBUILD';
    ELSE IF (@Fragmentation >= 5.0)
        SET @IndexScript = 'ALTER INDEX ' + @IndexName + ' ON ' + @SchemaName + '.' + @TableName + ' REORGANIZE';
    ELSE
        SET @IndexScript = NULL;

    IF (@IndexScript IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR (@IndexScript, 10, 0) WITH NOWAIT
        WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';
        EXEC(@IndexScript); 
    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO
        @TableName,
        @IndexName,
        @SchemaName,
        @Fragmentation;
 
END 
 
CLOSE TableCursor;
 
DEALLOCATE TableCursor;
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty MS SQL:

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1="print '?' DBCC DBREINDEX ('?')" 
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1="print '?' UPDATE STATISTICS ?"
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1="print '?' DBCC DBREINDEX ('?',' ',80)"
```

Comment: There's been downvotes. What's wrong with this as a quick-and-dirty approach to getting some reindexing statements? As of 2023, DBREINDEX still works in latest SQL Server version.

Answer (score 0):

Oh man, I wouldn't suggest just rebuilding all your indexes on all databases/tables without seeing how fragmented they are. You are taking huge performance hits for no gains. Make sure you check the amount of fragmentation per index and act on it accordingly. Usually anything over 15% is worth a reorganize until 30% where you would opt for rebuild instead. This also depends on your page count, size of index and activity on your tables. Some tables will always have high fragmentation and may not be worth touching at all if all it does is add/delete constantly unless you're seeing a performance issue on those tables.